# Can't reach a shared storage on a Windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, shared-storage

I have NAS storage, sharing a folder.
When I'm logged in to a (specific) Windows server, trying to connect to that share - it fails.
But when doing the same thing on a different server, it succeeds.
So I assume the issue is with my user profile on the specific server.

Any idea how to fix that? perhaps clearing cache of the user profile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it.. control panel > user accounts > manage your credentials > windows credentials - delete the credentials to the problematic NAS.